# Spring Boot allows duplicate annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I started a new `spring-Boot` project and I want to know why `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is allowed once we used `@SpringBootApplication`, because `@SpringBootApplication` itself has `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in it. Any reason for allowing this duplication?

Check the below code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration//why it is not prompting any error while using this annotation again?
public class Application 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may allow it (now), but it's not [recommended](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html)

> You need to opt-in to auto-configuration by adding the @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication annotations to one of your @Configuration classes.
>
> [Tip]
> You should only ever add one @SpringBootApplication or @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation. We generally recommend that you add one or the other to your primary @Configuration class only.

Comment: Yes I know that we should use only one of them. But my concern is if Spring boot it self is blocking it then the new Spring boot users will get to understand the things in a better way. Anyhow thanks for the reply.

Comment: @VamsiVegesna spring may not enforce rule,see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425620/why-autowired-on-irrelevant-method-is-ignored

Comment: Ok. If Spring does this in future it will be definitely helpful.